# React Native what exactly is the <> (empty) component

Tags: javascript, react-native, components, jsx

In React Native you can encapsulate a set of components in one single `<View>` (or similar) component. You can also encapsulate a set of components as `<>` and `</>`. What are these? Do they just translate to an base View? It's probably not a good practice but it doesn't give a warning and it doesn't crash.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

It's the React shortcut for `Fragment` component.

You can write like this :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Component extends Component {
  render() {
    return <> <ComponentA/> <ComponentB/> </>
  }
}
```

Or without the shortcut and import `Fragment` component

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react'

class Component extends Component {
  render() {
    return <Fragment> <ComponentA/> <ComponentB/> </Fragment>
  }
}
```

You have to know, you can't use any key or prop with the shortcut syntax.

Here's the [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html)

I hope it helps !

Comment: Ah, ok! I looked up the <> and </> itself but I got no result. Quite handy to know as it seemed just wrong to use a seemingly empty component. i'll mark it as answer when I can.

Answer (score 17):

In react `<> and </>` is just a syntactic sugar for `<React.Fragment>` . What it basically means is all components should be wrapped in a parent element. So without disturbing the whole schematic design <> provides a wrapper to wrap all your elemnts inside it .

```
<React.Fragment>
// your code
</React.Fragment>
```

is same as

```
<>
// your code 
</>
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thank you. What happens if we have no code at all between <> and </>, for example in a ternary operator in the case we want nothing ?

Comment: ill always advise null rather than empty fragments as it adds in the view tree

Comment: thank you. What is the code for null in this case?

Comment: @smartblonde why you would like to "render" null at all? Maybe missing something but in the end of the day JSX is used to render something to the DOM. You maybe asking if on some condition that is verified one doesn't want render. Then in this case a conditional render is useful and basically assign to null the variable for that case

Comment: <> </> allow also to avoid repeat extra <div></div> that could be need and also are not rendered in the DOM

Comment: @CarmineTambascia yes I've starting to use null instead of <></> in conditional rendering yes.

Answer (score 11):

In addition to what He has said, it is used to **embed many HTMLElements** that you don't what them to be nested into a `<div>` for example.

For example, you may have this use cases

```
render() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ChildA />
      <ChildB />
      <ChildC />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

For more explanation you can read this [React Official Documentation Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

Comment: He is about React Native. What is <div>?

Comment: @VladimirKovalchuk in React Native it might be <View> or any others components that can hold a child

Comment: But <div> doesn't behave as <View>. Any component can hold children. What is HTMLElements in React Native context?

Answer (score 6):

One of the highlights of React v16.2 is Fragments.
If you're working with React projects, you may be familiar with wrapping your child components with `<div>` or `<span>` in your render().

Fragment is a first-class component that you can use to wrap your child components and elements in place of `<div>` or `<span>` tags. Like so,

```
render(){
   return(
      <Fragment> 
        <h2>Heading</h2>
    <ChildA />
      </Fragment>
   );
}
```

or

```
render(){
   return(
      <React.Fragment> 
        <h2>Heading</h2>
    <ChildA />
      </React.Fragment>
   );
}
```

As a shortcut, you can also use empty tags `<></>` to indicate a fragment. Like so,

```
render(){
   return(
      <> 
        <h2>Heading</h2>
    <ChildA />
      </>
   );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you dont want to put extra `divs & spans`,

<></> will be nice pick for you

React does the replacement of `React.Fragment` component there

<></> == <React.Fragment></React.Fragment>