# Difference between <> and <div>

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to understand when to use `<>` and when to use `<div>` when writing React JS code.

The formatting is different when I switch between them but I'm not sure why.

Comment: can you provide a minimal example? I've used React for a while, and I've literally never seen anyone use `<>`

Comment: If you use `<div>` you'll get a div and it's children in dom, if you use `<>` you'll get *only* the children in dom.

Comment: `<>` is necessary when you want something like three `<input>` tags in a row, but you don't want them to end up in an actual HTML container. It's like a "phantom" container.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59751733/react-native-what-exactly-is-the-empty-component

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are Fragments in React 16 better than container divs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47761894/why-are-fragments-in-react-16-better-than-container-divs)

Comment: @DavidCulbreth - it's possible you're stuck on an older version of React that doesn't support this-- they're called [Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) and they've been around for a few years now-- `<></>` is the shorthand syntax for them.

Comment: Duuuuuude, this is so cool! TIL

Answer (score 1):

`<>Hello</>` is a JSX Element which renders to html text `Hello`.
`<div>Hello</div>` is a JSX Element containing a div that renders as `<div>Hello</div>`.